Unable to Invalidate Amazon Cognito IdToken
I’m working on a POC to implement user authentication using Amazon Cognito and the Amazon SDK for C#. My implementation utilizes the SRP authentication flow with MFA challenges. While I can successfully generate the IdToken, AccessToken, and RefreshToken for users, I’m encountering issues with logging users out. Despite invoking the logout method, Cognito continues to validate users as logged in. After extensive debugging, I found that while the AccessToken gets invalidated, the IdToken does not. How can I ensure the IdToken is also invalidated during the logout process?
Here's my code for login
public async Task<LoginUserResponse> LoginUser(LoginUserRequest loginUserRequest)
{

    var cognitoUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(loginUserRequest.userName);
    if (cognitoUser == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not Found");
    }
    var authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest
    {
        Password = loginUserRequest.Password
    };
    var authResponse = await cognitoUser.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest);
    return new LoginUserResponse
    {
        SessionId = authResponse.SessionID,
    };
}

and here's how I validate my otp
public async Task<ValidateLoginResponse> ValidateLogin(ValidateLoginRequest validateLoginUserRequest) 
{   
    AuthFlowResponse authResponse;

    var cognitoUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(validateLoginUserRequest.userName);
    if (cognitoUser == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not Found");
    }
    var otp =  _distributedCache.Get(validateLoginUserRequest.userName).ToString();
    if (otp != null)
    {
        validateLoginUserRequest.Otp = otp;
    }

    var authRequest = new RespondToMfaRequest
    {
        SessionID = validateLoginUserRequest.SessionId,
        MfaCode = validateLoginUserRequest.Otp,
        ChallengeNameType = ChallengeNameType.SMS_MFA
    };

    try
    {
        authResponse = await cognitoUser.RespondToMfaAuthAsync(authRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error Occur");
    }
    
    return new ValidateLoginResponse
    {
        AccessToken = authResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken,
        IdToken = authResponse.AuthenticationResult.IdToken,
        RefreshToken = authResponse.AuthenticationResult.RefreshToken
    };
}

Here's I currently log out users
public async Task Logout(string username)
{
    var cognitoUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(username);
    if (cognitoUser == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not Found");
    }
    cognitoUser.SignOut();
}

